# Why table doesn't have column

Tags: python, sql, database, backend, peewee

I use ORM-based package peewee. The following is my models.

```
@property
    def metamask(self) -> Type[Model]:
        model = self._account_model

        class Metamask(model):
            mnemonic = CharField(max_length=255)

        return Metamask

@property
    def _account_model(self) -> Type[Model]:
        db = self.__sql_db

        class AccountModel(Model):
            password = CharField(max_length=255)
            is_successful_authorized = BooleanField(null=True, default=None)

            class Meta:
                database = db
```

When I try to perform the following query

```
metamask_accounts = database.metamask.select().where(database.metamask.is_successful_authorized.is_null())
```

I give the error

```
peewee.OperationalError: no such column: t2.is_successful_authorized
```

But if I perform the query and try to access 'is_succcessful_authorized', it will work

```
database.metamask.select()
```

This is code of first query

```
SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."password", "t1"."is_successful_authorized", "t1"."mnemonic" FROM "metamask" AS "t1" WHERE ("t2"."is_successful_authorized" IS NULL)
```

So somehow it tries to select rows from t1, checking column matching from t2. How does this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you access those properties you are creating a complete new model class. Peewee sees these as different objects.

So:

```
m1 = database.metamask
m2 = database.metamask
m1 is m2  # False
```

You should use a cached property or some other less-convoluted construction.